# Get rid of a large blob in a binary image but keep smaller blobs in python with PIL or skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have two images:

[image]
[image]

Exuse the different resolution but that's not the point. On the left I have a "large" blob due to a camera reflection. I want to get rid of that blob, so closing the blob. But on the right I have smaller blobs that are valuable information that I need to keep. 
Both of these image need to undergo the same algorithm.
If I use a simple opening the smaller blobs will be gone, too. Is there an easy way to implement this in Python with skimage or/and PIL?

In a perfect world the left image should just create a white circle, where the right image should have the black dots within the white circle. It is okay to change the size of the black dots on the right image.

Here is an image which should describe the problem at the image directly [image]

Comment: are you talking about the black spots within the white area or what? add some annotations to your image. also provide your input image. your "large blob" has also small ones nearby, are they wanted too?

Comment: yes that's what I meant. I hope the new image clears that up, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You could detect all the black blobs and set a treshold so that blobs larger than the treshold are deleted.

Comment: and how do you know the difference? your computer is dumb, you have to teach him what is good and bad. http://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/#measuring-regions-properties

Comment: The problem I ran into using blob detection was that instead of finding one large blob it thought that the large blob was a series of smaller blobs. So there would be no difference to the other image

Comment: @Kev1n91 By any chance is the binary image of a retina? and are you working on detecting microaneurysms?

Comment: @Jeru Luke Yes indeed it is. I did not want to give the whole background cause I thought it would not be needed for understanding the problem. But here: I am currently trying to learn deep-learning convolutional networks, thus I tried the kaggle competition (I am not participating, the competition is over, it is just for learning)  to detect diabetic retinopathy. Problem is that the flash of the camera sometimes looks like the disease. So the black dots are the disease, while the large black blob is the flash from the camera

Comment: T identify flash from the camera take the heatmap of the retina image. The portion that is bright will be intense. The same approach can be used to identify the optic disc

Comment: But then again the disease itself would appear as a hot area

Comment: How about you find contours in the given images and retain those below are certain area while you neglect the bigger ones. The bigger blobs can then be masked.

Comment: Yes I thought about something like this. But I was hoping for an easier approach, sth like concatinating different kinds of morpholical filters , but seems like the hard way has to be followed.

Comment: @Kev1n91 were you able to come up with a solution?

Comment: Not till now. I will continue working on this problem soon.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So before I answer. I have to tell you that this is a hackish way and has no scientific background.

```
from skimage import io, measure
import numpy as np
img = io.imread('img.png', as_grey=True)
img = np.invert(img>0)
labeled_img = measure.label(img)
labels = np.unique(labeled_img)
newimg = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
for label in labels:
    if np.sum(labeled_img==label) < 250:
        newimg = newimg + (labeled_img==label)
io.imshow(newimg)
io.show()
```

Since this is a hackish way, I know I should have commented rather answered, but I don't have enough points to comment.